# Add class into current assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, activator, roslyn

I have a current assembly in my application and I would like to add a class from external cs file into this assembly. Is it possible to do it? I would like to use it like plug-ins. Now I'm trying use:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

and Activator,but without success. My application is using Roslyn, so maybe it can do it.
Any idea will be appreciated.

Edit: Next problem with it is: Can I use external file (cs file with class) to get instance from this file but the constructor of class needs reference to sceneManager from current assembley. So is possible to send a reference to Roslyn of something like that and get instance of class from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify an existing assembly that has already been loaded.

Instead, you can compile code to a new assembly (using Roslyn, CodeDOM, Sigil, or similar libraries) and load that assembly using reflection.

Answer (score 3):

A '.cs' file by itself is *just text*. You can't do *anything* with it without compiling it through some route. But no: you can't add extra classes into an assembly at runtime. You *can* compile the code at runtime via `CSharpCodeProvider` or similar, and load the generated assembly. It is a lot of messing, though. Depending on the context, tools like Iron Python may be preferable, if you need to do a lot of things from scripts at runtime.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Roslyn for run-time scripting, so I try to load new assembly with it.

Comment: When I think about it I found a little problem. I need to create instance of a class from file (out of my assembly), but constructor needs reference to sceneManager from current assembly. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @wolen possible? sure; trivial? no; somehow you need to pass that instance over, which could involve assembly references, or could involve passing it as `object`

Comment: "trivial? no" That scares me a little. But I'll try to find some article about it and solve it.